# Error on running python code with server action

Tags: python, odoo, action, odoo-9

I'm using odoo to develop an app which includes massive importation of data to a database.
The procedure it's simple I created an object with char variables only so they can be equal to everything, thenIi read every line from an excel template for each line a new record for this object is created.
Now I want to run a server action when all the excel lines where loaded, this way I can process every data, assign variables and choose a variable type for each column with another object I created.
The problem is using server actions you can run a piece of code after the excel file is loaded with this line `object.import_pricelist()` but object, who is supposed to be a reference for my model it's a NoneType and has no method `import_pricelist`

Server Action Def.

```
<record id="action_python_import" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Import PriceList</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_product_raw"/>
    <field name="condition">True</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">object.import_pricelist()</field>
</record>
```

Model and Method def

```
class ProductRaw(models.Model):
_name="product.raw"

name = fields.Char("Product Name")
price = fields.Char("Product Price")
vendor_code = fields.Char("Vendor Code")
product_code = fields.Char("Product Code")
flag_processed = fields.Boolean("Processed",default=False)
flag_error = fields.Boolean("Error",default=False)
error_desc = fields.Char("Error Description")

@api.multi
def import_pricelist(self):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` should be a reference to your model, object is a reference to `active_id`, if provided in the context.
If you are trying to run a method that is not connected to any particular object of the model (you want to create objects if I understand you correctly), than you should use `@api.model` decorator instead of `@api.multi`, and self instead of `object`, like this:

```
    <field name="code">self.import_pricelist()</field>
```

Please let me know if I helped.